# How do you install udevadm via command line?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

I need to run `udevadm trigger` but it says

`udevadm: missing or unknown command`

How do I install this via the command line?

Comment: `apt-get install udev` should install it

Answer (score 19):

`apt install udev` should install it.

However, I just had this same problem when it was already installed! That message is from udevadm telling you it needs a command.

Try running `udevadm monitor`

Edit: just noticed you were passing `trigger`, my best guess is that this is an unknown subcommand for whatever version of udevadm you have. For the record, here is what I get on Ubuntu 18.04:

```
$ udevadm
udevadm: missing or unknown command
$ udevadm trigger
$ udevadm monitor
monitor will print the received events for:
...
```